# Is it possible to automatically lock a file on Alfresco when editing via samba?

Tags: samba, alfresco

My question is pretty straightforward.

Using OpenOffice or Microsoft Office, is it possible to automatically lock a file for edition on the Alfresco file system via Samba?

For example, if a user goes to the samba directory, click on a file for editing it, it would be locked. When he finish to edit it (close the document), this document would be reopen to everyone.

Thanks for your help :)